# SQL Joins.Fetch data from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables (these are demo tables and not actual ones).
I can get data from test1 and test2 using JOIN but cannot get data from test3 under a specific condition.

In below given tables ID3=ID-ID2 (two IDs are separated using - and used as primary key in test3).

I want to get isShipped value from test3 when there exists ID-ID2 (if exists) along with all the columns in test1 and test2 (isShipped=default_value, when there doesn't exists ID1-ID2 in test3).

[image]

Comment: can you please add foriegn key references too.....?

Comment: Request you to add sample input data and output data. it will really help.

Comment: As you're doing join, it's joining ID of test1 with ID of test2.However, there is no ID in test3 so you cannot join.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I joined the two tables i.e test1 and test2 to get the required results and  to see if ID-ID2 exists in test3 i had to make another request to DB (i know frequently hitting DB data slows down the application) because right now i don't know how can i implement this in single SQL query.    user_ID+"."+resultSet.getString(1) (which boils down to ID-ID2). I had to  hit DB every single time for all the results in resultset while looping.

Comment: Those look like Sql Server screen captures, but the question is tagged MySql. They are very different database engines. Are you sure you tagged the question right? Getting this wrong will likely prevent us from giving you a good answer.

Comment: It is from SQL yog which is a GUI tool for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Test3 has no relationship with any table. You require to implement another unique resourceful identifier to make it significant to correlate the linkage of relationship between the identifiable three tables you have extrapolated.

Answer (score 0):

You want the condition `ID3 = ID - ID2` to be met.And you also want to have all the attributes from test1 and test2, for which you can use `full outer join` and state your condition in the where clause, assuming your ID's are integers and there is no null. N:B: This is what you do in Oracle database.Change it with similar semantics for MySQL, probably do some search online.

```
SELECT  c.isShipped
FROM    test1 a full outer join
        test2 b,
        test3 c

WHERE   c.ID3 = a.ID - b.ID2;
```

Comment: There is no full join in mysql - do you have a mysql alternative? Also the id3 appears to be a compound key made up in the form id-id2.

Comment: Well I use oracle sql.I believe then the OP need to replace full outer join with something similar in MySQL.

Comment: You use implicit joins in Oracle?

Comment: So what full outer join does is that it lets to join on matching attributes and at the same time it keeps unmatched attributes from both left and right.However there will be no tuple present if the attributes don't match so you basically get a white space or null.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture i assume that the ID's are VARCHARS? Perhaps try something like this:

```
SELECT t3.ID3, t3.isShipped
FROM test1 t1
JOIN test2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
JOIN test3 t3 ON t1.ID + '-' + t2.ID2 = t3.ID3;
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b542/1)

Comment: Can you do this with explicit joins rather than the disapproved of implict joins? Also + is not a concat shortcut in mysql.

Comment: I updated to reflect explicit joins. Based on SQL Fiddle, it appears as though the + works as a concat.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql try

```
select t1.*,t2.*,t3.isshipped
from    test1 t1
join  test2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
join    test3 t3 on t3.id3  = concat(t2.id,'-',t2.id2)
```